# Should callers of an interface (need to) make assumptions about the underlying implementation?

Tags: java, interface, api-design

I understand the benefit of Programming to an Interface and the benefit of using an Interface for the return type of a method:

```
public List<Integer> getUserIds() {
    return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
}
```

I wonder if this is still applicable when the method callers rely on a particular implementation to function correctly? For example,

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final Map<Integer, String> map = getUserIdMap();
    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

    // print user name in the order of their Ids
    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : entrySet) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static Map<Integer, String> getUserIdMap() {
    final Map<Integer, String> s = new TreeMap<>();
    s.put(3, "Tracer");
    s.put(2, "John");
    s.put(5, "Jane");
    s.put(6, "Jenny");
    s.put(1, "Rob");
    return s;
}
```

In this case, is it better for getUserIdMap() to return a SortedMap instead of Map so that the method caller does not need to guess the map's underlying implementation? Or is it generally better to return a Map because the method entrySet() belongs to Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be bad for client code that uses an interface to depend on an implementation detail that is not documented on the interface.

In your example, the `Set` and `Map` interfaces make no guarantees about the order of the elements inside them, so it would be bad for the client to make assumptions about them.

But this is not a problem in your case, as there are more specific sub-interfaces of `Set` and `Map` that do make guarantees about order. They are `java.util.SortedSet` and `java.util.SortedMap`. If your client code uses these interfaces, then they *are allowed* to make assumptions about order.

`TreeSet` and `TreeMap` implement these interfaces, respectively.

From the Javadoc for `SortedMap`:

> A `Map` that further provides a *total ordering* on its
>   keys.

Answer (score 0):

### The tradeoff

Your example is a case of trading off the method designer's freedom against the method user's freedom.

For the method designer, it is nicer to return `Map`, so that she can change her mind later with respect to the implementation if a better approach comes up.

For the method caller, it is nicer to receive a `SortedMap`, so she can rely on the contents to be sorted rather than having to sort them herself.

### How to make it

The proper way to think about the situation (for the method designer) is to try and foresee the future:

- Will I likely want to later change my implementation to use a *non-sorted* `Map`?
- Will my caller likely want to receive a *sorted* result?

If the answer to the latter question is yes, this is likely the more important of the two, because data structures of implementations are changed only rarely in practice -- but inconvenience to the callers is, um, inconvenient.

### How to break it

The worst possible outcome is that both participants go their preferred way at the same time: The designer only guarantees `Map`, but the caller *still* relies on receiving a `SortedMap`. Modularization is broken.

Do this in enough spots in a large system and you will have lots of trouble when you *really* need to change an implementation.

Moral: As a designer, make as many guarantees to your users as you can -- but no more.